# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, are the following statements known to hold in general?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, inequalities, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This has been cross-posted to [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300684).  However, I feel that it is more likely to receive a good answer here, because I believe that it *is* a research-level question.  For the mathematicians who voted to put this question on hold, I invite you to peruse this [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6001) to give you an inkling of where I'm driving at.  Thanks!)

Let $\sigma$ be the classical sum-of-divisors function.

A number is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(N)=2N$.

If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$ (i.e., $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$), are the following statements known to hold in general?

> $\bf{(a)}$ $\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$ is *large*.
>
> $\bf{(b)}$ The deficiency $D(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$ is *large*.
>
> $\bf{(c)}$ The *index* $i(q^k) = \sigma(N/q^k)/q^k$ is *large*.

Using the *trivial* relationships:

$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})} = i(q^k) = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}$$

then if the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture that $k = 1$ is true, it is possible to show that a lower bound for the quantities $\bf{(a)}$, $\bf{(b)}$ and $\bf{(c)}$ is given by $n/\sqrt{3}$.  (Here, I have used [Acquaah and Konyagin](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1793042112500935)'s estimate $q < n\sqrt{3}$. The inequality $q^k < n^2$ then gives the desired *large* numerical bound if we use known lower bounds for the odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$, latest of which are by Ochem and Rao.)

What happens when $k > 1$?  I do know that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k \geq 315$ by using a result of [Broughan, Delbourgo, and Zhou](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf).

Is it possible to do better than this, apart from attempting a proof of (*obviously*) $q^k < n$?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question?  =(

Answer (score 0):

If $k > 1$, we can do better if the following inequalities hold:

> $$q < q^k < n.$$

The resulting lower bound is

> $$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})} = i(q^k) = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} > \frac{8}{5}\cdot\frac{n^2}{q^k} > \frac{8}{5}\cdot{n}.$$

Since $k > 1$ implies $q < n$, it remains to consider the case

> $$q < n < q^k.$$

(**Update (February 2016)**: In a recent preprint, Brown claims a complete proof for $q < n$, and a partial proof for the inequality $q^k < n$.  If completed, Brown's proof then rules out this last remaining case.)